# query multiple subclass property

Tags: sparql, protege

I want to query a class "Soto Kebumen" based on the subclass with sparql

[image]

I have tried this query, but it cant query both "makanan_Dari some Jawa_Tengah" and
"memiliki_Bahan some Bunga_Brokoli"

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX kb: <http://www.qassobi.uns.ac.id/kebudayaan#>
PREFIX bm: <http://www.qassobi.uns.ac.id/bahan_makanan#>
PREFIX wl: <http://www.qassobi.uns.ac.id/wilayah#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
SELECT ?makanan 
    WHERE { ?makanan rdfs:subClassOf* kb:Makanan_Daerah .
?makanan rdfs:subClassOf [
owl:onProperty kb:makanan_Dari;
owl:someValuesFrom wl:Jawa_Tengah;
] .
?makanan rdfs:subClassOf [
owl:onProperty kb:memiliki_Bahan;
owl:someValuesFrom bm:Bunga_Kol;
]
 }
```

But, it return a result if I only query one of each..

```
SELECT ?makanan 
    WHERE { ?makanan rdfs:subClassOf* kb:Makanan_Daerah .
?makanan rdfs:subClassOf [
owl:onProperty kb:makanan_Dari;
owl:someValuesFrom wl:Jawa_Tengah;
]
```

and

```
SELECT ?makanan 
    WHERE { ?makanan rdfs:subClassOf* kb:Makanan_Daerah .
?makanan rdfs:subClassOf [
owl:onProperty kb:memiliki_Bahan;
owl:someValuesFrom bm:Bunga_Kol;
] }
```

[image]

How to query multiple subclass property and get the above result?

Comment: Are you sure that `bm:Bunga_Kol` is correct? It doesn't match the `Bunga_Brokoli` in your screenshot

Comment: @AKSW omg, didn't realize that. The query worked after I changed to `Bunga_Brokoli`